# Активность полей в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть два чекбокса, допустим, `android` и `ios` плюс два мультиселекта ниже - назовем их `android-select` и `ios-select` (чтобы не заморачиваться с подключением плагина в примере будут просто два инпута). Чекбоксы оба изначально выбраны.

Условия следующие:

- если выбраны оба чекбокса, оба инпута активны;
- если не выбран ни один чекбокс, оба инпута активны;
- если выбран `android`, `ios-select` становится неактивным, `android-select` - соответственно, активен;
- если выбран `ios`, `android-select` неактивен, `ios-select` - активен.

Я написал скрипт, но весь сценарий в нем отразить не удалось (когда выбраны оба чекбокса инпуты неактивны) да и в целом я понимаю что он кривой/косой и так делать не следует. Просьба показать более правильный и лаконичный вариант...

[Песочница](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/GrmjZG).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#android').is(':checked')) {
    $('#ios-select').addClass('inactive');
  } else {
    $('#ios-select').removeClass('inactive');
  }
});
$('#android').on('change', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    $('#ios-select').addClass('inactive');
  } else {
    $('#ios-select').removeClass('inactive');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#ios').is(':checked')) {
    $('#android-select').addClass('inactive');
  } else {
    $('#android-select').removeClass('inactive');
  }
});
$('#ios').on('change', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    $('#android-select').addClass('inactive');
  } else {
    $('#android-select').removeClass('inactive');
  }
});
```

```css
.checkbox-block {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.multiselect-block > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.multiselect-block input.inactive {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-block">
  <input id="android" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="android">Android</label>
  
  <input id="ios" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="ios">iOS</label>
</div>
<div class="multiselect-block">
  <div>
    <input id="android-select" type="text" placeholder="android-select" >
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="ios-select" type="text" placeholder="ios-select">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверять, на активность все поля

Вариант JS:

```js
var android = document.getElementById('android'),
  ios = document.getElementById('ios'),
  android_select = document.getElementById('android-select'),
  ios_select = document.getElementById('ios-select');

var ins = function() {
  if(android.checked == true){
    android_select.classList.remove('inactive');
  }else if(ios.checked == true){
    android_select.classList.add('inactive');
  }else{
    android_select.classList.remove('inactive');
    ios_select.classList.remove('inactive');
  };
  if(ios.checked == true){
    ios_select.classList.remove('inactive');
  }else if(android.checked == true){
    ios_select.classList.add('inactive');
  }else{
    android_select.classList.remove('inactive');
    ios_select.classList.remove('inactive');
  };
};

window.onload = function() {
  ins();
};
document.getElementById('android').onchange = function() {
  ins();
};
document.getElementById('ios').onchange = function() {
  ins();
};
```

```css
.checkbox-block {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.multiselect-block > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.multiselect-block input.inactive {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-block">
  <input id="android" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="android">Android</label>
  
  <input id="ios" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="ios">iOS</label>
</div>
<div class="multiselect-block">
  <div>
    <input id="android-select" type="text" placeholder="android-select" >
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="ios-select" type="text" placeholder="ios-select">
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант Jquery:

```js
var android = $('#android'),
  ios = $('#ios'),
  android_select = $('#android-select'),
  ios_select = $('#ios-select');

var ins = function() {
  if(android.prop('checked')){
    android_select.removeClass('inactive');
  }else if(ios.prop('checked')){
    android_select.addClass('inactive');
  }else{
    android_select.removeClass('inactive');
    ios_select.removeClass('inactive');
  };
  if(ios.prop('checked')){
    ios_select.removeClass('inactive');
  }else if(android.prop('checked')){
    ios_select.addClass('inactive');
  }else{
    android_select.removeClass('inactive');
    ios_select.removeClass('inactive');
  };
};

$(function() {
  ins();
});
android.change(function() {
  ins();
});
ios.change(function() {
  ins();
});
```

```css
.checkbox-block {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.multiselect-block > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.multiselect-block input.inactive {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-block">
  <input id="android" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="android">Android</label>
  
  <input id="ios" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="ios">iOS</label>
</div>
<div class="multiselect-block">
  <div>
    <input id="android-select" type="text" placeholder="android-select" >
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="ios-select" type="text" placeholder="ios-select">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZmgWZ

```
function changed(e){
  var checkedLen = $('.checkbox-block input:checked').length;

  $('.multiselect-block input').removeClass('inactive');

  if( checkedLen == 1){
      var $checkInput = ($('.checkbox-block input:checked').attr('id') == 'android') ? 'ios' : 'android';
      $('#'+$checkInput+'-select').addClass('inactive');
  }   
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox-block input').on('change', changed);
    changed()
});
```